# html table code in php

Tags: php, html

I need to know where I'm going wrong with this. It's create a table in PHP some code giving not working. Any help much appreciated Thanks.

```
<?php
echo"
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <th>Fruit</th>
  <th>%</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Apples</td>
  <td>44%</td>
  <td>Bananas</td>
  <td>23%</td>
  <td>Oranges</td>
  <td>13%</td>
</tr>
</table>";
echo "<br>";
echo "
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>23</td>
  <td>Bill</td>
  <td>25</td>
  <td>Roy</td>
  <td>18</td>
</tr>
<table>";
?>
```

Keep getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting ',' or ';' on line 5

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn basic PHP syntax:

```
echo"
    ^---starts a string
<table border="1">
              ^--- TERMINATES the string
```

And this is not just a PHP thing. This is true of ANY language. You cannot embed quote characters inside a string which is delimited by that very same quote character, WITHOUT using some other means of embedding the quote char: escaping, concatenating with different style-quoted strings, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can't use unescaped `"` characters in a string that is delimited with `"` characters.

```
echo"
    ^ start of string
<table border="1">
              ^^error
              ^end of string
```

There's no need for that to even be in a string in the first place though. Just stay outside of `<?php php mode ?>` and let the HTML be output directly.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this instead. `echo "<table border=\"1\">"` or `echo "<table border='1'>"`**

In php, you can use either single quote(') or double quote(") for a string. If you use `echo "";` you must use single quote inside double quotes or the other way around.